# Log showing BinderProxy@45d459c0 is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android

i have one activity Main Activity There is one web view , i want load web view when broadcast receiver receiver message ,also there is one service class which pass data to activity web view ,if activity is open and any message receive from receiver URL load successfully but when i close app there is error window leaked, i have shown many answer but i didn't  resolved it,please help me

here is main activity interface method which load URL

```
  @Override
public void setwebview(String url) {
    Log.d("URL@@", "" + url);
    webView.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);
}
```

here is on start command method of service class where pass data to activity

```
public void onCreate() {
    isRunning = true;
    Log.d("CALLLL@@", "onCreate");
    String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds") String ANDROID_ID = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Log.d("DEVICE_ID@@", " YES : " + ANDROID_ID);
    mainUrl = "http://tr.adsx.bid/url4app.php?device=" + ANDROID_ID + "&rand=" + uniqueId;


    context = getApplicationContext();
    if (timer != null && timerTask != null) {
        timerTask.cancel();
        timer.cancel();
    }
    String abc = Util.ReadSharePrefrence(context, START);
    if (abc.equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
        callApi(mainUrl, "stop");
        Log.d("PREF@@", "" + abc);
    } else if (abc.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
        callApi(mainUrl, "start");
        Util.WriteSharePrefrence(context, START, "start");
        Log.d("PREF@@", "else" + abc);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    if (timer != null && timerTask != null) {
        timerTask.cancel();
        timer.cancel();
    }

    callApi(mainUrl, "stop");
    isRunning = false;
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

  @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    isRunning = true;
    if (intent != null) {
        jsurl = intent.getStringExtra("JSURL");
        if (jsurl != null) {
            serviceInterface.setwebview(jsurl);
        }
    }
    Log.d("CALLLL@@", "onStart");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

here is broadcast receiver class

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Received...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            assert pdusObj != null;
            for (Object aPdusObj : pdusObj) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aPdusObj);

                switch (SMSNUMBER = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress()) {
                }
                SMS = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + SMSNUMBER + "; message: " + SMS);

                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: " + SMSNUMBER + ", message: " + SMS, duration).show();

                String javaScriptUrl = Util.ReadSharePrefrence(context, JAVASCRIPTURL);
                Log.d("JAVAURL@@", "SMS" + javaScriptUrl);

                String newString = javaScriptUrl.replace("SMSMACRO", SMS);
                Log.d("JAVAURL@@", "SMS" + newString);

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AutoOpenAppService.class);
                intent1.putExtra("JSURL", newString);
                context.startService(intent1);

              /*  Util.WriteSharePrefrence(context, jsurl, newString);
                context.startService(new Intent(context, AutoOpenAppService.class));*/
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you unregistered Broadcast receiver ? if not then you have to unregistered it when your activity is done . As per guideline in onPause() of Activity.

Comment: yes, i did but app crash before open, and i register it in manifest also

Comment: "i register it in manifest also "  you register it twice why ? just register and unregister it at runtime.

Comment: thanks for reply but i register only in manifest not any other

Comment: well thats not the right way as much i get from above code . Anyway you need to check for Activity's isFinishing() in onReceive() each time .

Comment: can u please tell me how to do it?

Comment: if first time i open the app and didn't get any message that means receiver not call , than after i close also goign to crash

Comment: Its all depends upon sendBroadcast(). From where you are getting this broadcast?

Comment: i got solution , i have added this code in receiver class
 PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();Intent LaunchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.your.packagename");
                LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                LaunchIntent.putExtra("JSURL", newString);
                context.startActivity(LaunchIntent);

Answer (score 0):

If You are Having any AlertDialog Check its Context and Check whether the Activity is Running.

This is most likely happening because you are trying to show a dialog after execution of a background thread, while the Activity is being destroyed.

I was seeing this error reported once in a while from some of my apps when the activity calling the dialog was finishing for some reason or another when it tried to show a dialog. Here's what solved it for me:

```
  @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(!((Activity) context).isFinishing())
    {
        //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

[Check this Link](http://dimitar.me/android-displaying-dialogs-from-background-threads/)

From the stack trace above, it appears that the facebook library spins off the auth operation asynchronously, and you have a Handler - Callback mechanism (onComplete called on a listener) that could easily create this scenario.

Comment: Did you used any Function from anothr Class? Are you having a Dialog or Some functions  having Context as a Parameter

Comment: Try Changing `return super.onUnbind(intent);` to `return true`

Comment: MAy be the Timer is causing the problem. Check the number of instances of the timer and also check whether the timer is properly Cancele and destroyed